# Spawning multiple sprite nodes with the same properties

Tags: ios, swift, nodes, skspritenode

I'm trying to make a game which spawns nodes that will come down from the top of the screen. I want my programme to choose from a multitude of nodes with the same properties(but they look different). Is there a way of making an array of nodes that I can apply the properties to at the same time, rather than having to go through each one and right it all out over and over. 
I'm a beginner coder and haven't got any code to show except for the variables that I have already.

```
    var SY = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "slowYellow")
    let SG = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "slowGreen")
    let SP = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "slowPurple")
    let SR = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "slowRed")
    let FY = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fastYellow")
    let FG = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "normalGreen")
    let FP = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "normalPurple")
    let FR = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fastRed")
    let NY = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "normalYellow")
    let NG = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "normalGreen")
    let NP = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "normalPurple")
    let NR = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "normalRed")
    let SB = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "slowBlack")
    let NB = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "normalBlack")
    let FB = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fastBlack")
```

Comment: The best thing to do here is probably to use a designated initialiser like: `initWithColor:` that sets the other properties in it's implementation.

Comment: How would I do this? Also the nodes I'm using use images that I've already made in other softwares (.png), can I still use "initWithColor:"

Answer (score 1):

### This sounds like the ideal candidate for **subclassing**

[Subclassing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID195) allows you to **setup common functionality** for a given superclass (in your case, `SKSpriteNode`). This will allow you to create multiple objects with the same base functionality.

You can create your own convenience initialiser ([it's not technically overriding `SKSpriteNode`'s convenience init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322421/convenience-init-override)) and  setup your common properties there. For example:

```
class MyCustomNode: SKSpriteNode {

    convenience init(imageNamed name:String) {

        let tex = SKTexture(imageNamed: name);
        let nodeSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);

        self.init(texture: tex, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: nodeSize)

        // Do extra setup for common functionality here
    }  
}
```

Then, in order to use it, I recommend you create an array of your image names and create the nodes in a for loop. For example:

```
let birds :[String] = ["slowYellow", "slowGreen", "slowPurple", "slowRed", "fastYellow", "fastGreen", "fastPurple", "fastRed", "normalYellow", "normalGreen", "normalPurple", "normalRed", "slowBlack", "normalBlack", "fastBlack"]

var birdNodes = [MyCustomNode]()
for bird in birds {
    let node = MyCustomNode(imageNamed: bird)
    node.position = // do position logic
    addChild(node)
    birdNodes.append(node)
}
```

You can then refer to your bird sprites through the `birdNodes` array.

You can also go further by overriding more functions to further customise your subclass.

I suggest you have a look at the [Swift documentation on inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html). That will give you a good start on subclassing.

Comment: Thanks for that, so can I just add the files to the subclass like this:
        `convenience init(imageNamed name: ["slowYellow", "slowGreen", "slowPurple", "slowRed", "fastYellow", "fastGreen", "fastPurple", "fastRed", "normalYellow", "normalGreen", "normalPurple", "normalRed", "slowBlack", "normalBlack", "fastBlack"]) {`

Comment: no, you'd want to define your array of image names *outside* of the subclass (as they're unique), and then perhaps use a for loop to create each of your objects, looping through the names in the array and initialising each node with that.

Comment: Oh okay, so I've made my array of images now. Sorry to sound like an idiot but which parts of the source code you gave me do I edit to fit my coding? I've called my array "birds". Thanks

Comment: I have added a usage example to my answer

Comment: When I put this into my program it tells me that the for loop has an error and  "expected declaration", what does this mean?

Comment: @Cockettino add the code to the OP... there's a chance you're just missing a bracket or something