# Swift: Overriding a convenience initializer

Tags: ios, swift, macos, initialization

In Swift, is there a pattern to produce the semantic equivalent of overriding a convenience initializer?

Behaviorally, this what I'd like to do:

```
class MyScene: SCNScene {
   convenience init(URL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]?) {
       super.init(URL: url, options: options)

       .... other initialization
   }
}
```

Yes, I understand initializer chaining and why you can't actually do this directly;  however, it seems like a reasonable and frequently needed behavior.

Sure, I could make my own convenience initializer which does the same thing as the superclass, and calls a designated superclass initializer.  But since I'm subclassing an opaque system class, I don't necessarily know how to reconstruct the behavior.

Any way to do this or a design pattern which obviates the need for this?

Comment: You can override a convenience initialiser, you just don't need the `override` keyword. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322421/convenience-init-override What is your actual problem?

Comment: That's not the same thing.  I want to inherit the behavior of the superclass initializer, not replace it.

Comment: You do inherit the superclass initialiser, by default,  but you said you wanted to override it. I don't understand your question

Comment: You don't need to know what the superclass initialiser does. You just call it via `super`.  Are you perhaps getting confused by SCNScene's use of class factory methods rather than initializers?

Comment: No, that's doesn't work.  You can't call a convenience initializer of a superclass. In the above snippit, I would need to call a designated superclass initializer, which in this case would be `init()` or `init(coder)`

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I get it now. No, you can't do that. You would need to set your additional properties after initialisation.

Comment: Right, but you can't add properties in an extension.  Currently, I'm using a factory method which does what you suggest, but it feels very clumsy.  Seems like there should be some way to implement this behavior...?

Comment: Yes, I revised my comment to remove the reference to extension. I haven't done anything with SceneKit but it looks like SCNScene is almost a "final" class